# Twisted redirect subdirectory to another domain

Tags: python, redirect, dns, twisted

I'm hosting a couple domains static files with Twisted. However, for a subdirectory of the domain, I want to redirect to another domain.

For example: Serve foo.com static files, but foo.com/bar goes to foobar.com/bar

I can't seem to find anything in the Twisted docs for this scenario.

## Update

I replied to Glyph that it wasn't working, but I had placed it in the wrong spot. His suggestion was, of course, absolutely correct. I should have provided more initial info. Here it is implemented:

```
from twisted.application import internet, service
from twisted.web import static, server, vhost, script
from twisted.web.util import Redirect


root = vhost.NameVirtualHost()

# Add a default -- htdocs
root.default=static.File("/home/foo")
root.putChild("myredirect", Redirect("http://othersite.com/myredirect"))

# Add a simple virtual host -- bar.com
root.addHost("bar", static.File("bar"))

# Add a simple virtual host -- foo.com
root.addHost("foo", static.File("/home/foo"))

application = service.Application('web')
sc = service.IServiceCollection(application)
site = server.Site(root)
i = internet.TCPServer(80, site)
i.setServiceParent(sc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward, although it depends on how your site is set up.

Basically though,

```
from twisted.web.util import Redirect
fooDotComResource.putChild("bar", Redirect("http://foobar.com/bar"))
```

Comment: Sorry Glyph, I should have been more specific

Comment: root = vhost.NameVirtualHost()

# Add a default -- htdocs
root.default=static.File("/home/joesteel/foo")

# Add a simple virtual host -- bar.com
root.addHost("bar.com", static.File("/home/joesteel/bar"))

# Add a simple virtual host -- foo.com
root.addHost("foo.photos", static.File("/home/joesteel/foo"))

application = service.Application('web')
sc = service.IServiceCollection(application)
site = server.Site(root)
#site.putChild("selfies", Redirect("http://www.512pixels.net/the-worlds-greatest-selfies/"))
i = internet.TCPServer(80, site)
i.setServiceParent(sc)

Comment: You should edit your question if there are more pertinent details.  Apart from being basically totally unreadable in that comment, it's hard to integrate this information with your question without some more words.  When you add this code to the question, add some words about why Glyph's answer doesn't help.